# Mounting and recovering HDD from img

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I’ve managed to use ddrescue to create an img file of my dead HDD. 690GB. How can I now attempt to recover data from the .img in Linux?

Is there a way to mount it or some tools that auto recover data from it?

Comment: if you are just asking for a software [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily convert the image into a block device which will act like a raw hard drive by using the following commands:

```
losetup loop0 /path/to/imagefile.img
```

This will create a device "/dev/loop0" which is equivalent to /dev/sda.  You can then use

```
kpartx -a /dev/loop0
```

To create partitions which existed on the drive - note that the partitions will exist in /dev/**mapper**/loop0pX rather then /dev/loop0

If these are regular partitions you can then mount them with the regular mount command like mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /path/to/mount - or you can activate LVM using the appropriate LVM commands etc.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to recover data from an img-file:

---

### The Sleuth Kit

with [The Sleuth Kit](https://sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/) you can recover/extract files from an img-file directly.

1. install it by opening a terminal and insert (assuming you are using a debian-derivate):
   `sudo apt update && sudo apt install sleuthkit`
2. extracting files and saving them in a choosen folder:
   `tsk_recover -a path/to/ddrescue.img /path/to/folder/for/recovered/files`

tsk_recover has some other useful options, so i would advise to read its [man-page](https://sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/man/tsk_recover.html).

---

### kpartx

with [kpartx](https://linux.die.net/man/8/kpartx) you can mount the img-file and cherry-pick the needed files with your preferred file-manager, which maybe will need much less space and time if you just need a few files.

1. install it by opening a terminal and insert (assuming you are using a debian-derivate):
   `sudo apt update && sudo apt install kpartx`
2. mounting all partitions present in the img-file:
   `sudo kpartx -a path/to/ddrescue.img`
3. unmounting all partitions present in the img-file:
   `sudo kpartx -d path/to/ddrescue.img`

---

### mount

(for this case) pretty the same as with kpartx can be achieved with mount.

1. mounting all partitions present in the img-file:
   `sudo mount -o loop path/to/ddrescue.img /media/loop_mount`
2. unmounting all partitions present in the img-file:
   `sudo umount /media/loop_mount`